# Kotlin Mockito always return object passed as an argument

Tags: java, kotlin, junit, mockito, mockk

I am trying to use Mockito on my mocked object in such a way that it should always return the very same object that was passed in as an argument. I tried it do to it like so:

```
private val dal = mockk<UserDal> {
    Mockito.`when`(insert(any())).thenAnswer { doAnswer { i -> i.arguments[0] } }
}
```

However, this line always fails with:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: UserDal(#1).insert(null)
```

The `insert(user: User)` method doesn't take in `null` as an argument (obviously `User` is not a nullable type).

How can I make the `insert()` method always return the same object that it received as an argument?

Comment: Do you create and pass the `user` in the test code ? Or it's created somewhere else in the code under test ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I create and pass it in the test code. But the setup line is not in the actual test, it's before, on the top of the test class, before any test.

Comment: Then add a line in the test that return the specific instance when insert() is called. I don't think that it's a bad design

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel This is not what I want, and especially doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Wait. Why are you using Mockito to tell what a MockK mock should do? Use MockK, or use Mockito. Don't mix both.

Comment: @JBNizet Any example how to do that with Mockk?

Comment: `private val dal = mockk<UserDal> { every { insert(any<User>()) } returnsArgument 0 }`. But do you understand that it makes no sense to use Mockito to tell what a MockK mock should do? These are different mocking frameworks. Choose one, and read its documentation. MockK is a better choice for Kotlin, IMHO

Comment: @JBNizet I do understand, but I didn't find a way to do it with Mockk. And I can't resolve this method `returnsArgument`, where does it come from? Hm probably newer version. I'm on 1.8

Comment: From the public API of MockK (I use it in version 1.9.1). See https://github.com/mockk/mockk/blob/2244688efc2439eb0a67fec595e26ab53f2ee324/dsl/common/src/main/kotlin/io/mockk/API.kt#L2143-L2144.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you're using *MockK* you should not use *Mockito*.

Only using *MockK* you can achieve the same with:

```
val dal = mockk<UserDal> {
    every { insert(any()) } returnsArgument 0
}
```

If you intend to use *Mockito*, you should remove *MockK* and use [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin):

```
val dal = mock<UserDal> {
    on { insert(any()) } doAnswer { it.arguments[0] }
}
```